# CRC Polynomial Division

Tags: algorithm, division, checksum, crc, polynomials

I am trying to use polynomial division to find the CRC check bits, but I am struggling with the last stage of the calculation.

I am believe the below conversions are correct:

```
Pattern = 1010 
        = x^3 + x

Dataword = 9 8 7 
         = 1001 1000 0111
         = x^11 + x^8 + x^7 + x^2 + x + 1
```

And finally the polynomial long division I am attempted is:

```
              x^8 + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x
        _______________________________________
x^3 + x | x^11 + x^8 + x^7 + x^2 + x + 1
          x^11 + x^9

        ....
              x^4 + x^2 + x + 1
              x^4 + x^2

                  = x + 1
```

My question is, is the remainder / answer *x + 1* or do I take it a step further and remove the *x* leaving the remainder as just *1*?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It is x + 1, i.e. the CRC checksum is `0011`. That is, if your calculations are correct

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks for your response mate! Maybe there is an error with my calculation then, because when I add it to the end of the data and do the division again my answer is not zero...

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, the checksum is 3 bits, and it should be `110` if I am not mistaken. Probably there is an error in your computation

Comment: See https://www.ghsi.de/CRC/indexDetails.php?Polynom=1010&Message=987

Comment: @NiklasB. Thank you! I was using '011' instead and thats why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

We can check by `mod 2` division (`XOR`) too, the following code shows a `python` implementation of CRC checking, we need to follow the steps listed below:

- Convert CRC / data polynomials to corresponding binary equivalents.
- if the CRC key (binary representation obtained from the polynomial) has *k* bits, we need to pad an additional *k-1* bits with the data to check for errors. In the example given, the bits `011` should be appended to the data, not `0011`, since `k=4`.

At the transmitter end,

- The binary data is to be augmented first by adding k-1 zeros in the end of the data.
- Use modulo-2 binary division to divide binary data by the CRC key and store remainder of division.
- Append the remainder at the end of the data to form the encoded data and send the same

At the receiver end (Check if there are errors introduced in transmission)

- Perform modulo-2 division again on the sent data with the CRC key and if the remainder is 0, then there are no errors.

Now let's implement the above:

```
def CRC_polynomial_to_bin_code(pol):
    return bin(eval(pol.replace('^', '**').replace('x','2')))[2:]

def get_remainder(data_bin, gen_bin):
    ng = len(gen_bin)
    data_bin += '0'*(ng-1)
    nd = len(data_bin)
    divisor = gen_bin
    i = 0
    remainder = ''
    print('\nmod 2 division steps:')
    print('divisor dividend remainder')
    while i < nd:
        j = i + ng - len(remainder)
        if j > nd: 
            remainder += data_bin[i:]
            break
        dividend = remainder + data_bin[i:j]
        remainder = ''.join(['1' if dividend[k] != gen_bin[k] else '0' for k in range(ng)])
        print('{:8s} {:8s} {:8s}'.format(divisor, dividend, remainder[1:]))
        remainder = remainder.lstrip('0')
        i = j
    return remainder.zfill(ng-1)

gen_bin = CRC_polynomial_to_bin_code('x^3+x')
data_bin = CRC_polynomial_to_bin_code('x^11 + x^8 + x^7 + x^2 + x + 1') 
print('transmitter end:\n\nCRC key: {}, data: {}'.format(gen_bin, data_bin))
r = get_remainder(data_bin, gen_bin)
data_crc = data_bin + r
print('\nencoded data: {}'.format(data_crc))
print('\nreceiver end:')
r = get_remainder(data_crc, gen_bin)
print('\nremainder {}'.format(r))

if eval(r) == 0:
    print('data received at the receiver end has no errors')

# ---------------------------------
# transmitter end:
# 
# CRC key: 1010, data: 100110000111
# 
# mod 2 division steps:
# divisor dividend remainder
# 1010     1001     011     
# 1010     1110     100     
# 1010     1000     010     
# 1010     1000     010     
# 1010     1011     001     
# 1010     1100     110     
# 1010     1100     110     
# 
# encoded data: 100110000111110
# ---------------------------------
# receiver end:
# 
# mod 2 division steps:
# divisor dividend remainder
# 1010     1001     011     
# 1010     1110     100     
# 1010     1000     010     
# 1010     1000     010     
# 1010     1011     001     
# 1010     1111     101     
# 1010     1010     000     
# 
# remainder 000
# data received at the receiver end has no errors
# ---------------------------------
```